# 'URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden' when pushing a magento site into Heroku

Tags: php, magento, heroku

This is probably a very simple question, but I'm quite new with both Magento and Heroku.

I am trying to host my magento code to have an instance of the app that I can work with besides the original code. After I created a heroku app, and tried to push, I got the following error:

remote:          The 'https://repo.magento.com/....zip' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
remote:
remote:
remote:        install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []...
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to ...
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/...git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://...git'

I understand that the problem is with authorization, so I tried finding a way to override that, but beyond that I have no real idea on how to go about fixing this. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks.